# Вывод картинки через LibXCB

Tags: linux, c, gui, xorg

Библиотека плохо документирована, но может кто может привести пример программы на C, показывающей картинку через вызовы библиотеки xcb?

Comment: Почти тот же вопрос на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029489/how-to-display-an-image-into-an-xcb-window

Answer (score 2):

Здесь [документация с примерами](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libxcb/tutorial/index.html), а Вам будет [интересен этот раздел](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libxcb/tutorial/index.html#pixmaps).

Comment: TODO: Give an example, or a link to xpoints.c

Вот именно это я и имел в виду говоря о плохой документированности.
Из описания непонятно как заполнять созданную картинку своими данными.

есть другой сайт, но там всё то же самое:
http://xcb.freedesktop.org/